# Eclipse Git project no indexer

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I imported a git project into Eclipse Luna. I want to build indexer on the project. However, when I right click there is no Build Indexer option. In addition, under "Properties" I don't see "C/C++ Build" or "C/C++ General" options.

Comment: Was the project initially created as a C/C++ project? Eclipse might not have detected the correct project type when you imported it.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse looks for the project natures to determine the project type. As Tyler said, maybe they were not imported correctly or never existed.

- Right click on project
- `New` ↦ `Other` ↦ `Convert to a C/C++ Project (Adds C/C++ Nature)`
- Select your setting in the dialog.

Maybe you still need to add the builders either via the project properties and then `Builders` (dunno how exactly) or just replace/add the `<buildSpec></buildSpec>` in the `.project` file in the root directory of your projects with

```
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.genmakebuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ScannerConfigBuilder</name>
        <triggers>full,incremental,</triggers>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
```